# Prove that function is differentiable at point $a$ only if $f(x) - f(a) = \phi(x)(x-a)$, where $\phi$ is continuos at $a$

Tags: real-analysis

Then $\lim_{x \to a}\frac{f(x) - f(a)}{x - a} = \frac{\phi(x)(x - a)}{x - a} = \phi(a)$ if $\phi$ is continous at $a$.

If $\lim_{x \to a}\phi(x)$ does not exist, function indeed is not  differentiable at $a$.

But what if $\lim_{x \to a}\phi(x) = A$, so that limit exists, but implies that $\phi(x)$ is not continuos at $a$?

Comment: You're interpreting the statement wrongly (it's not unambiguously phrased). It should be "$f$ is differentiable at $a$ if and only there is a $\phi$ that is continuous at $a$ such that $f(x) - f(a) = \phi(x)(x-a)$ [for all $x$ where $f$ is defined]". Among the $\phi$ satisfying the equality, there are always ones that are discontinuous at $a$.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is differentiable at $a\in \mathbb{R}$. We have to show that there is a function $\phi:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x)-f(a)=\phi(x)(x-a)$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$ and $\phi$ is continuous at $a$.

Define $\phi(x)=\frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}$ for all $x\neq a$ which we can obviously do. Define $\phi(a)=\lim_{x\rightarrow a}\frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}=f'(a)$. The latter makes sense since we assume that $f'(a)$ exists. Now $\phi$ is a well-defined function. We have to show that $\lim_{x\rightarrow a}\phi(x)=\phi(a)$, but this is the same as stating that $\lim_{x\rightarrow a}\frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}=\phi(a)$, and hence is true. By definition $f(x)-f(a)=\phi(x)(x-a)$ for all $x\in \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: $\phi(a) \ne \lim_{x\rightarrow a}\frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}$. It is not valid to replace function value by it's limit in the point. $\phi(x)$ is not defined at $a$ in this case.

Comment: Look at Daniel Fischer's comment.